# Controlar excepción DataIntegrityViolationException dke

Tags: java, spring-boot

Como puedo validar la excepción cuando el usuario trate de ingresar un nuevo registro con un correo que ya existe que hace las veces de llave primaria? Y como regresar el mensaje de error al formulario?

**ClienteRestController**

```
//Método refactorizado de validación
private List<String> obtenerErrores(BindingResult result) {

    List<String> errors = result.getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(err -> "El campo '" + err.getField() + "' " + err.getDefaultMessage())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return errors;
}

@PostMapping("/clientes")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody Cliente cliente, BindingResult result) {

    Cliente clienteNew = null;

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        response.put("errors", this.obtenerErrores(result));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }

    try {
        clienteNew = clienteService.save(cliente);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        response.put("mensaje", "!Error al intentar crear el registro en la base de datos!");
        response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    response.put("mensaje", "!El registro del cliente ha sido creado con éxito!");
    response.put("cliente", clienteNew);

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: Antes de cliente el usuario podrias ejecutar un query para buscarlo antes de guardarlo para no "tratar de adivinar" que el `DataAccessException` es un error por duplicacion.

Answer (score 0):

La solución era validar si se producía esa excepción especifica ***Duplicate entry***

```
@PostMapping("/clientes")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody Cliente cliente, BindingResult result)
        throws DataIntegrityViolationException {

    Cliente clienteNew = null;

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        response.put("errors", this.obtenerErrores(result));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }

    try {
        clienteNew = clienteService.save(cliente);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof DataAccessException) {
            response.put("mensaje", "!Error al intentar crear el registro en la base de datos!");
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(((NestedRuntimeException) e).getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        }   
        if (((NestedRuntimeException) e).getMostSpecificCause().getMessage().startsWith("Duplicate entry")) {
            response.put("mensaje", "!El correo :".concat(cliente.getEmail()).concat(" ya existe en la base de datos"));
            response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(((NestedRuntimeException) e).getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("mensaje", "!El registro del cliente ha sido creado con éxito!");
    response.put("cliente", clienteNew);

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```